# Arguments contains expressions in functions?

Tags: javascript

i am total newbie to JS.
now i have read in a book this code.

```
var sayMessage = new Function("message", "console.log(message);");
```

My Question is where are the `{}` in this function. 
i mean how can we write `message", "console.log(message);` where there needs to be a argument? 
thanks.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Comment: @adeneo can you please explain me in short.... Thay is why i put up the question. Ofcourse there is documentation and many books but i wanted to know a concise answer..

Comment: `new Function` isn't an expression, like `function() {}`, it's a constructor with it's own set of arguments, that are well documented.

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini: Those are **strings**. They are arguments to the `new Function` constructor. There is no function expression (that would require `function ( ) { }` tokens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript `Function` constructor can be used to define functions from strings. The constructor will evaluate the string passed as the last argument as the function body.

> Function objects created with the Function constructor are parsed when the function is created. This is less efficient than declaring a function with a function expression or function statement and calling it within your code, because such functions are parsed with the rest of the code.

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

---

That means this statement:

```
var sayMessage = new Function("message", "console.log(message);");
```

will be evaluated to this expression:

```
var sayMessage = function (message) {
    console.log(message);
};
```

You can see how the arguments `message` and `console.log(message)` map from one to the other.

There are very few reasons why you would like to do this in the first place, and it is rarely seen in idiomatic JavaScript.